# AWS CLI, DynamoDB scan with 2 filters

Tags: aws-cli, dynamodb-queries

I have this scan but I need to put an aditional filter:

```
aws dynamodb scan 
  --table-name my-table 
  --filter-expression "attribute_type(#code.#cor, :v_sub)" 
  --expression-attribute-names '{"#code": "sender", "#cor": "custom:myAttribute"}'
  --expression-attribute-values '{":v_sub":{"S":"N"}}'
```

This works fine but now I want to scan only when the attribute `createdAt` (it's a string date) CONTAINS the string `2020-10`

I was trying something like:

```
aws dynamodb scan 
  --table-name my-table 
  --scan-filter '{"createdAt":{"AttributeValueList": [{"S":"2020-10"}], "ComparisonOperator": "CONTAINS"}}' 
  --filter-expression "attribute_type(#code.#cor, :v_sub)" 
  --expression-attribute-names '{"#code": "sender", "#cor": "custom:myAttribute", "#created": "createdAt"}' 
  --expression-attribute-values '{":v_sub":{"S":"N"}, ":date":{"S":"S"}}'
```

But I get a: `Can not use both expression and non-expression parameters in the same request: Non-expression parameters: {ScanFilter} Expression parameters: {FilterExpression}`

How can I filter for that comparison operator CONTAINS in my working scan?

Answer (score 3):

I had to use only `filter-expression` each filter with `and` and using the function `contains()`:

```
aws dynamodb scan 
  --table-name my-table 
  --select "COUNT" 
  --filter-expression "attribute_type(#code.#cor, :v_sub) and contains(createdAt,:created)" 
  --expression-attribute-names '{"#code": "sender", "#cor": "custom:myAttribute"}' 
  --expression-attribute-values '{":v_sub":{"S":"N"}, ":created":{"S": "2020-10"}}
```